# Git branch commits exist in every other branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I've been using git for a while, but today I encountered something really strange. I recently created a branch and did some heavy upgrades to a our web framework.

I committed the changes and switched over to the master branch, only to discover all the new files from the upgrade existing on the master branch as well. I tried googling this among other things, but I can't figure out what has caused this.

Edit: for clarity, the commits don't exist in master, only the files from the upgrade branch.

Comment: Google for "git lga" and try it to see what you've done to all your branches at once

Comment: You almost certainly forgot to `git add` the new files before committing, so they were and still are "untracked files" that git just leaves around whenever you switch from branch to branch.

Comment: @torek Nope I certainly added everything and committed it.

Comment: I have seen a similar behavior when for example, I create new branch X and add certain files to my `.gitignore` while in that branch. Then I would switch to the master branch --where those files haven't been marked to be ignored-- and I would see all the files from the branch X in the master branch.